# Import a single export seems to import the whole js file. How can I import just the exported object?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Exporting from one file index.js like this: `export const categoriesObj = new Object();` and trying to import from another index.js file like this: `import { categoriesObj } from "../app/index.js";`, but I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: (variable from the other file) is not defined because instead of just importing the categoriesObj, I think is importing the whole file.
Currently I'm using webpack and babel. Both index.js files have separate bundle files. The folder structure looks like this:

- dist

  - bundle1.js
  - bundle2.js
- src

  - app

    - index.js
  - history

    - index.js

What I have tried is:

- Add "type": "module" in package.json file.
- Added babel-loader. Thought it was some problem with ES6 modules.
- renamed ../app/index.js to index.mjs.

What I'm trying to do is to import an object which is generated in another file so I can use it on this other file.
Hope this makes sense. I've been stuck in this for days. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Top-level code in a module is executed when you are importing it, so it's not like the JS engine scans the code looking for the exact word you are importing, ignoring everything else on the way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only is a thing.

Comment: Don't put code that you don't want to run in the module that you import.

Comment: An `import` declaration *always* loads and evaluates the whole imported module (and its dependencies). There is no way to run only a part of it. The identifiers in the declaration only allow choosing which of all the exports you want to have available, and under what alias, in the current module.